# Как работает @RenderBody в ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться с дерективой @RenderBody, зачем она нужна?
я знаю, что она используется в макете страницы (или мастер-странице) и что вместо нее должны поставляться представления, но я не понимаю как это должно работать, могли бы Вы привести хороший пример для понимания данной директивы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Директива Razor @RenderBody, превращает наш код в ASP.NET Core, написанный на адской смеси С#, HTML + JS, в то, что может быть в качестве ответа, принято  и расшифровано браузерами. Вот в этом [видео](https://youtu.be/yG55PpZ7w1k) дается краткое описание структуры файла _Layout, и блока с этой командой, для Razor Pages под .NET 6.